# Relación de muchos a muchos en 2 tablas usando una tabla pivote

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

**Estoy generando un reporte de emergencias en la cual tengo 2 tablas una que se llama `vehículos` y otra que se llama `registros_emergencia`, la cual tiene en común las relaciones un registro puede tener varias unidades y una unidad puede tener varios registros**

[image: Diagrama de las 2 tablas con su relación]

Modelo de Registro_emergencia

```
<?php
namespace Xhunter\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Registro extends Model
{
protected $table = 'registro_emergencia';

protected $fillable = [
    'personal_id',
    'emergencias_id',
    'sub_estaciones',
    'emergencia',
    'descripción_emergencia',
    'dirección',
    'num_escoltas',
    'personas_atendidas',
    'hora_salida',
    'hora_retorno',
    'fecha_reporte'
];

public function personal()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Personal::class);
}

public function vehiculos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Vehiculo::class);
}

public function emergencias()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Emergencia::class);
}

#region Accesores
public function getNamePersonalAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->personal->nombre_completo}";
}

public function getNameVehiculoAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->vehiculos->vehiculo_unidad}";
}

public function getNameEmergenciaAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->emergencias->tipo_emergencia}";
}
#endregion }
```

Modelo Vehiculo

```
<?php
namespace Xhunter\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Vehiculo extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'imagen',
    'vehiculo_unidad',
    'num_serie',
    'inventario',
    'no_motor',
    'marca',
    'modelo',
    'placas',
    'estatus_vehiculo'
];

public function registro()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Registro::class);
}}
```

Migración `tabla pivote` con las referencias a las tablas

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateReportesUnidades extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reportes_unidades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('registro_id')->unsigned();
  $table->foreign('registro_id')->references('id')->on('registro_emergencia');
        $table->integer('vehiculos_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('vehiculos_id')->references('id')->on('vehiculos');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('reportes_unidades');
}
}
```

**Entonces la pregunta es como hacer para que a la hora de guardar el registro del reporte y mediante un `checkbox` seleccione las unidades como generar el guardado de los datos mediante la `tabla pivote`.

Si necesitan que suba el código del formulario en la cual mando a llamar los `vehículos` comenten por aquí de antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo.**

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia. ¿Que haz intentado?

Comment: A simple vista, creo que podrías usar attach o sync https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships. Intenta algo, y si no funciona agrégalo a la pregunta

Comment: Varios comentarios que hacerte, primero revertí tu edición pues no es válido coloques la solución en la misma pregunta, segundo si vas a responder a tu propia pregunta usa por favor la parte de abajo que es la zona de respuestas y finalmente no coloques imágenes sino que en su lugar coloca el código como texto, seleccionalo y presiona `ctrl + k` para darle formato

Comment: ok muchas gracias por el aporte me podrías proporcionar solución para la ultima pregunta? puesto que siguiendo la documentación se hace uso de un foreach y traes los datos de la relacion en mi caso si lo hace pero me trae la ultima relacion no todas